# How to COUNT and SUM from a table in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

1) I have a table named "plan_info_upload" which is like:

```
site_id site_name   2G_bw   3G_bw   route_path
1       MBCGP1      11      30      MBLMA1>MBSMGR
2       BOPBG2      12      22      BOPBG2>BOBET16
3       BOPCB1      11      0       BOBET16>BOGBT1>BOPBG2>BOBET16
4       BOSBB1      14      25      BOSBB1>BOKDG1>BOBET16>BOGBT1
```

2) & a unique_hop list like this:

```
serial_id   unique_hop
1           MBLMA1>MBSMGR
2           BOPBG2>BOBET16
3           BOBET16>BOGBT1
4           BOGBT1>BOPBG2
5           BOSBB1>BOKDG1
6           BOKDG1>BOBET16
```

3) Now I have find unique hop from the route_path from the 1st table, then how many 2g_bw & 3g_bw it has & total 2g_bw & 3g_bw how many 2G_bw & 3G_bw each hop has & their total bandwidth.
In my code I can not use SUM function. And it shows me individually result, not the total number of 2G & total bandwidth. How can I solve this?

```
<?php 
    $unique_hop=$_POST['unique_hop'];
    $i = 0;
    $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM plan_info_upload";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $route_path = $row['route_path'];
            $site_name = $row['site_name'];
            $bw_2g = $row['2G_bw'];
            $bw_3g = $row['3G_bw'];
            $total_2G_bw = 0;
            $no_of_2G = 0;
            $total_3G_bw = 0;

            if(strpos($route_path, $unique_hop) !== false)
            {
                $no_2G = COUNT($site_name);
                $no_of_2G = $no_2G + $no_of_2G;
                $total_2G_bw = $bw_2g + $total_2G_bw;

               // $no_3G = COUNT($site_name);
                //$no_of_2G = $no_2G + $no_of_2G;
                $total_3G_bw = $bw_3g + $total_3G_bw;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo ++$i;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $unique_hop;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $no_of_2G;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $total_2G_bw;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $total_3G_bw;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

As any hop can not have 3G bw then I have to check if that hop has 3G bw value or not, if it has then it count 1 in no_of_3G. How to COUNT and SUM 2g_bw & 3g_bw?

My desire output will be like this.

```
unique_hop     no_of_2G   total_2G_bw   no_of_3G   total_3G_bw
BOPBG2>BOBET16   2          23           1           22
```

**One unique hop may have more than one site_name. Abd there is possible that one hop does not have any 3G bandwidth.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you are obtaining the `total_2G_bw` and `total_3G_bw` columns in your desired output?  Can you show us how you arrive at these values for the hop `MBLMA1>MBSMGR` ?

Comment: after searching in the route path of 1st table, there is only one hop "MBLMA1>MBSMGR" & that is in the 1st row. so from that row I found there is one 2G & 1 3G value of bandwidth. So no_of_2G & no_of_3G is 1 & 1. & their value is 11 & 30 which will be total_2G_bw & total_3G_bw respectively. If there is more than one route path which is contain the hop, then it will count & sum the 2G_bw & 3G_bw. I hope you understand.

Comment: What does the data look like for `BOPBG2>BOBET16` which has 2 2G and 3G values?

Comment: yes. & also their total bandwidth. data will be look like the table provided in point 3.

Comment: I am trying to understand your code and I am fairly certain it will not be the result you provided in 3 for e.g. $no_of_2G. Can you give the actual output? And what is your desired output? Your main problem is your database "design" that forces you to emulate the calculations a database would (easily) do. If I understood you correctly: To get a sum for all, you will have to sum yourself by getting all rows (not only for the chosen $unique_hop). To get sum per hop, you still need more loops. Or fix your database design. Summing and counting and grouping (by e.g. hops) is what databases are for.

Comment: Please again read the post. I added my desired output & actual output. I want sum & count of every unique hop. but can not solve it. how to arrange my database & solve this problem? Or is there any other way to get this desired result?? please help me. @Solarflare

Comment: You pass "unique_hop" as `post` parameter, thats why they all are same. You also initialize all variables inside a loop. Thats why they don't incremented.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$unique_hop=$_POST['unique_hop']; 
$i = 0;
$sql4 = "SELECT COUNT(nullif(2G_bw, 0)) AS no_of_2G, SUM(2G_bw) AS total_2G_bw, COUNT(nullif(3G_bw, 0)) AS no_of_3G, SUM(3G_bw) AS total_3G_bw FROM plan_info_upload WHERE route_path LIKE '%$unique_hop%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $no_of_2G = $row['no_of_2G'];
        $total_2G_bw = $row['total_2G_bw'];
        $no_of_3G = $row['no_of_3G'];
        $total_3G_bw = $row['total_3G_bw'];
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo ++$i;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $unique_hop;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $no_of_2G;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $total_2G_bw;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $no_of_3G;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $total_3G_bw;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```